# Apollo Federation Resolve Array from IDs

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-federation

I am using MongoDB as the database for my federated Apollo GraphQL API.

(My code is in TypeScript)

I have created a `__resolveReference` method for the `Post` resolvers object, and **this works fine when I call it from the `user service` as follows:**

```
User: {
...
    firstPost(user: any) {
            return { __typename: "Post", _id: user.firstPost };
        },
     }
...
}
```

However, when I call it on an array, it does not work. The following is how I call it:

```
User: {
...
      posts(user: any) {
            user.posts.map((x: any) => {
                return { __typename: "Post", _id: x };
            });
      },
...
}
```

The post `__resolveReference` code follows:

```
Post: {
...
async __resolveReference(reference: any, { db }: any) {
            console.log(reference);
            console.log(reference._id);
            try {
                let r = (await db
                    .collection("posts")
                    .findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(reference._id) })) as Post;

                console.log(r.content);

                return r;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
            }
        },
...
```

I know that the `__resolveReference` is not being "hit" when called from the `posts` resolver on the `User` object because the `console.log()`s are not shown in the Terminal, again, only from the `posts` resolver and not `firstPost`.

I would like some help in getting the `__resolveReference` working for arrays.

Thank you.

Comment: The firstPost and posts resolvers should be implemented in the Post service not in the User service. You should extend the User type on your Post type to build a reference, like so: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/#federated-schema-example

Answer (score 3):

Using an array to resolve reference should work.

If you create a new list instead of changing a resolver input, this snippet of code will work.

```js
User: {
...
  posts(user: any) {
        let postlist = [];
        user.posts.forEach(postId => postlist .push({ __typename: "Post", _id: postId }));
        return postlist;
}      
...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In Apollo Federation return array in `__resolveReference` doesn't work properly if you want to return a array a solution is create a new type.
For example, if you have `User` implemented in one service and post in another
a simple representation of `User` and `Post` Model are something like this:

```
typescript
-- User Service
    type User{
        id: ID!
        email: String!
        password: String!
    }

-- Post Service
    type Post{
        id: ID!
        content: String!
        postedBy: ID!
        date: Date
        comments: [String]!
    } 

Add a reference to Post type

    //define a key in Post
    type Post @key(fields:"id") 
    
    //Add a field on User like
    type User{
        id: ID!
        email: String!
        password: String!
        post: [Post]!
    }
    
    extend type Post @key(fields:"id"){
        id: ID! @external
    }
```

This method doesn't work.
A solution is to create a new type in `Post Service`:

```js
    type PostList @key(fields: "idUser"){
        idUser: ID!
        posts: [Post]!
    }
    
    PostList : {
        __resolveReference(reference){
            //data is a array of post
            let userPost = data.filter((p)=>{p.postedBy==reference.idUser})
            return {idUser: reference.idUser, posts: userPost}
        }
    }
```

And in your `User` service do this:

```js
    type User{
        id: ID!
        email: String!
        password: String!
        posts: PostList
    }
    
    extend type PostList @key(fields:"idUser"){
        idUser: ID! @external
    }
    
    in User resolver
    User : {
        posts(_parent){
            return {__typename: "PostList", idUser: _parent.id}
        }
    }
```

And see if `__resolveReference` work with `async/await` functions.

Comment: What if they do not have any relation on the post side, this will eventually just violate separation of concern and doesnt look like a proper solution for this problem. :/

For example i have a Post and a Channel where it is posted

Post {
  channels: [Channel]
}

there is no relation to post on the channel side and should not be.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this would be to `extend` the `User` type on the `Post` service.

*I am using [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs) in this example, You can resolve your data using any fetch function, but the practice is the same.*

**Post Service**

```
const resolvers = {
  User: {
    posts: async (root: any) => await prisma.post.findMany({ where: { userId: root.id } }),
  },
};

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Post {
    id: ID!
  }

  extend type User @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID! @external
    posts: [Post]!
  }
`
```

**User Service**

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: async (_root: any, args: any) => await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: args.id } })
  },
  User: {
    __resolveReference: async (root: any) => await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: root.id } }),
  },
};

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    user(id: ID!): User
  }

  type User @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID!
  }
`
```